# Coordinate transfer with Poincare transformation

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, field-theory, inertial-frames

How to use
$$
x^{\alpha} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}x’^{\mu}+a^{\alpha}
$$
to prove
$$
\eta^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} = \eta^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu^{'}}\partial_{\nu^{'}}
$$
where $\partial_{\mu} = \partial/\partial{x^{\mu}}$ and $\partial_{\mu^{'}} = \partial/\partial{x’^{\mu}}$?
And what does $\partial^{\mu}$ equal?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}
$$
and the property $\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x'^\mu}=\Lambda^\alpha_{\;\mu}$ to find
$$
\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial'_\mu\partial'_\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\Lambda^\alpha_{\;\mu}\Lambda^\beta_{\;\nu}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\;.
$$
Now it is left to see that $\eta^{\mu\nu}\Lambda^\alpha_{\;\mu}\Lambda^\beta_{\;\nu}$ is the $(\alpha,\beta)$ entry of the matrix product $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda$, which is $\eta^{\alpha\beta}$, since the Lorentz-transform $\Lambda$ leaves the inner product defined by $\eta$ invariant. This is pretty much the definition of a Lorentz-transform, because they are defined to leave the scalar quantity
$$
ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-c^2dt^2=d\vec{x}^T\eta d\vec{x}
$$
(depends on the chosen signature of $\eta$, here chosen to be $(+,+,+,-)$) invariant. That means
$$
d\vec{x}^T\eta d\vec{x}=d\vec{x}'^T\eta d\vec{x}'=d\vec{x}^T\Lambda^T\eta \Lambda d\vec{x}\;,
$$
using the definition from above. This is completely analogous to how orthognal matrices $O$ leave the standard inner product in Euclidean space unaltered, so
$$
\vec{a}^T\mathbb{1}\vec{b}\equiv\langle\vec{a}\lvert\vec{b}\rangle=\langle\vec{a}'\lvert\vec{b}'\rangle\equiv\vec{a}'^T\mathbb{1}\vec{b}'
$$
for any $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ if (and only if) $\vec{a}=O\vec{a}',\vec{b}=O\vec{b}'$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$, meaning it satisfies $O^T\mathbb{1}O\equiv O^TO=\mathbb{1}$. The metric here is simply $\mathbb{1}$(identity in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

More generally, in Minkowski space every object $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^4$ which under change of intertial frames transforms like $d\vec{x}$, so $\vec{v}'=\Lambda\vec{v}$, is called "a vector". With the simple metric of flat spacetime the partial derivative $\partial_\mu$ is a vector, and since $\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$ is just the inner product $\vec{\partial}^T\eta\vec{\partial}$ (which should never be written like this :) ) it remains invariant under Lorentz-Transforms.

It is worth noting that in general relativity the metric changes from the simple diagonal form. Lorentz-transformations are then only performed on a local flat spacetime which is in some sense tangent to the global curved spacetime. However, considering the overall metric, $\partial_\mu$ is not a vector anymore, it doesn't transform correctly under change of inertial frames. To formulate the laws of physics independently from the chosen reference frame, one has to introduce a different kind of derivative, often called $\nabla_\mu$, which coincides with the usual $\partial_\mu$ only in a flat spacetime where $\eta=diag(+1,+1,+1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First:
$$x^α = Λ^α_μ {x'}^μ + a^α ⇒ dx^α = Λ^α_μ d{x'}^μ ⇒ \frac{∂}{∂{x'}^μ} = Λ^α_μ \frac{∂}{∂x^α}.$$
Thus, second:
$$\begin{align}
η^{μν} \frac{∂}{∂{x'}^μ} \frac{∂}{∂{x'}^ν} &= η^{μν} Λ^α_μ \frac{∂}{∂x^α} Λ^β_ν \frac{∂}{∂x^β} \\
&= η^{μν} Λ^α_μ Λ^β_ν \frac{∂}{∂x^α} \frac{∂}{∂x^β} \\
&= η^{αβ} \frac{∂}{∂x^α} \frac{∂}{∂x^β}
\end{align}$$
since
$$η^{μν} Λ^α_μ Λ^β_ν = η^{αβ}$$
is the defining property of $Λ$.

Finally, in common usage are:
$$∂_μ = \frac{∂}{∂x^μ}, \hspace 1em ∂^μ = η^{μν} ∂_ν = η^{μν} \frac{∂}{∂x^ν}.$$